# Change the div content of an html from another html through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using iframe tags in my index.html. Below is the code

```
<iframe src="header.html" height="100px" scrolling="no" width="1335px"
        style="position: absolute; top: 0px;"></iframe>
    <iframe src="menu.html" height="500px" scrolling="no" width="250px"
        style="position: absolute; top: 103px;"></iframe>
    <iframe src="body.html" height="500px" scrolling="no" width="1083px"
        style="position: absolute; top: 103px; left: 260px"></iframe>
    <iframe src="footer.html" height="100px" scrolling="no" width="1335px"
        style="position: absolute; top: 605px;"></iframe>
```

My Login div is in menu.html and logout is in footer.html. I want to show logout when login div is hidden(after login) and when i click Logout i want my logout link to be hidden and login div to be displayed. Since both of them are in differnet html's so i want to know how we can do this simultaneaously. Right now this functionality is working but i need to refresh the page.
Also window.location.reload is not useful.
Is there any easier way to perform hide/show operations in multiple html's concurrently.

Comment: Hi, while what you are asking is possible, I must tell you that you should strongly think about dropping the iframes solution unless you have some very specific needs that requires them? If you are processing the main page with a server-side language, you could easily include the content of each individual files in your main HTML page without the need of iframes. This way, there would be a single document and you will not have to deal with cross-frame operations.

Comment: As @plalx said, this can be done, but why? If you own all those pages, then why in the world would you use iframes? They will only cause you extreme headaches trying to script between them. Better to use divs as you called your iframes in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really must keep this content in separate files and are intent on making separate calls for each, try this:

```
<div id="header" style="height: 100px; width 1335px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px;"></div>
<div id="menu" style="height: 500px; width 250px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 103px;"></div>
<div id="body" style="height: 500px; width: 1083; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 103px; left: 260px;"></div>
<div id="footer" style="height: 100px; weight:1335px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 605px;"></div>
```

And some jQuery like so:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#header").load("header.html");
   $("#menu").load("menu.html");
   $("#body").load("body.html");
   $("#footer").load("footer.html");
});
</script>
```

Now that you have all your markup in the same window, use jQuery to do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Replacing iframes with divs won't necessarily be that straightforward. There could be conflicts of IDs, and clashing scripts, etc.

Comment: No doubt @LeeTaylor. I was just trying to get him going in a better direction than the use of iframes. Based on what was presented in the question, this will have no conflicts, at least until the divs are loaded...

Comment: Also, the fewer ids the better